# Text label is not aligning with form boxes from layout

Tags: symfony, layout, twig, zurb-foundation

I've been following Symfony2 documentation on how to override a Twig form template which is working however there is one problem. The names of the fields are not lining up next to the form boxes.

I should be getting this:
[image]

But instead my Name and Email labels are not aligning. I get this:

[image]

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? (I've copied over the  code from the template and wrapped the form code with it.)

**Overridden template code**

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label class="inline"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 columns">
        {% spaceless %}
            {% set type = type|default('text') %}
            <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
        {% endspaceless %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}

{% block email_widget %}
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label class="inline"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 columns">
        {% spaceless %}
            {% set type = type|default('text') %}
            <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
        {% endspaceless %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock email_widget %}

{% block textarea_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <textarea rows="12" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>{{ value }}</textarea>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock textarea_widget %}
```

**Original Zurb Foundation template code** http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/contact.html

```
<form>
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label class="inline">Your Name</label>
     </div>

    <div class="large-10 columns">
        <input type="text" id="yourName" placeholder="Jane Smith">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label class="inline"> Your Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 columns">
        <input type="text" id="yourEmail" placeholder="jane@smithco.com">
    </div>
</div>

<label>What's up?</label>
    <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="radius button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. If you're not going to help then there is no point in being rude.

Comment: I don't like to be rude. But your questions look like "I have code provided by someone. But it doesn't work as I want. Please help me, solve this problem.". You are not trying to solve the problem yourself, you are hoping that someone solve all your problems and you will get working web-site. StackOverflow is not the Question-Answer answer site, it is a knowledge base. But if everyone will post questions like you, StackOverflow will become a dump.

Comment: I can help you but you need to learn technologies yourself. You look like a scholar who wants someone to help him do all the homework for him. But if you will do the 99% of your homework and will have a very complex problem then I (and many others) will help you to solve your problem but not the whole homework divided by many questions.

Comment: Instead of answering I can point you on a right way: see the html code generated by your controller. Compare it with your zurb-template. You will find that your label is generated outside your widget block. And to solve your problem you need to override `form_row` block or put label inside your `form_widget` and generate form "without" label. It is very simple. Many users saw your question and understood that it is very simple... But no one did answer! Think about it.

Comment: Well thank you sir, that made sense. Just didn't know about form_row and putting in the form label form there. It's all about helping people to understand and not reprimanding them when they don't. Not everyone is going to 'get' it right away and need help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Sivolobov for his guidance. Hope this helps others with the same question. Overwrote form_row and wrapped `{{ form_label(form) }}` in the `<div class>`.

```
% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div>
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <label class="inline">{{ form_label(form) }}</label>
            </div>
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```